# react native typescript get event target

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

i am new to react native with typescript and i have a problem
i want to get the text from the Text component so it mean when i press the Text i will console log it
i cant get the target value
i try also currentTarget
but it will give me a huge array of object with ton of keys without any target value

```
import { GestureResponderEvent, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "../../components/card/Card";
import ChooseLotteryNumber from "../../components/choose_lottery_number/ChooseLotteryNumber";
const CreateUser = () => {
  
  const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState<number[]>([]);
 
  const onSelectNumbers = (e: GestureResponderEvent )=>{
    console.log(e.currentTarget)
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Card>
        <View>
          <Text onPress={onSelectNumbers}>choose numbers!</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.number_container}>
        
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CreateUser;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  number_container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  number: {
    fontSize: 24,
    margin: 6,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    textAlign: "center",
    width: 35,
  },
});
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget.textContent`?

Comment: Not working. Get undifiend

Comment: And i dont have a textContent its react native , i have content if it help if you want i can a take picture of all the available method